# Format currency in all input scenarios

Tags: php, regex

Any regex experts that can solve this? Basically, need the same output on all the different scenarios. Just need to figure out the correct regex.

```
<?php

 // Inputs
$numbers = array(
"1234",
"1 234,00",
"1234.00",
"1234,00",
"1.234,00",
"1.234.00",
"1,234.00",
"1,234,567.00",
"123,456.00",
"1.234.567,00",
"1 234 567,00",
"-1234",
    );

foreach ($numbers as $number) {
    echo $number . " => " . my_number_format($number) . " <br />";
}

// Currency format
function my_number_format($number){
    // return number_format((double)$number, 2, ',', ' ');
    $number = preg_replace('#(\d),(\d)#','$1$2',$number);

    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'sv_SE');
    return money_format('%!i', $number);
}
 ?>
```

Comment: `1.234.00` --- what's this? A version number?

Comment: Use `str_replace` to replace the commas and spaces with the empty string, then you'll have very few cases to handle (manually).

Comment: @alfasin: I'd say "commas and dots with a space" (nice idea though)